# How can I get object by key?

Tags: javascript

```
var test = [
    {
        id   : 'user01',
        pos0 : 2 
    },
    {
        id   : 'user01',
        pos0 : 3 
    },
    {
        id   : 'user02',
        pos1 : 5 
    },
    {
        id   : 'user02',
        pos1 : 6 
    },
    {
        id   : 'user03',
        pos2 : 8 
    },
    {
        id   : 'user03',
        pos2 : 9 
    }
]
```

This is example data,

and
I want if I passed 'pos2', get test[4] and test[5].

```
//like this : 

function getObjectByKey(array, key){
    // dosomething
};

..
var testArray = getObjectByKet(test, 'pos2');
```

I tried to use $.inArray or $.map, but how to use them.
How can i do this?

Regards.

Comment: sorry, I mistaked. I edited question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,

```
 function getObjectByKey(array, key){
        var users=[];
        $.map(array, function (user, index) {
            if (user[key])
                users.push(user)
        });
        return users;
    };
```

hope this will help you.

Also change your function calling. You miss spelled the function name
Try this while calling the method

```
var testArray = getObjectByKey(test, 'pos2');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to iterate an array. Like this:

```
var test = [
    {
        id   : 'user01',
        pos0 : 2 
    },
    {
        id   : 'user01',
        pos0 : 3 
    },
    {
        id   : 'user02',
        pos1 : 5 
    },
    {
        id   : 'user02',
        pos1 : 6 
    },
    {
        id   : 'user03',
        pos2 : 8 
    },
    {
        id   : 'user03',
        pos2 : 9 
    }
]
var user;
test.map(function(v) { if(v.id == 'user03') user = v;  });
```

Here is a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gcjv0ux5/).